# OIOSAML: assertion consumer does not work

Tags: sso, saml

I wrote a simple system with SP-initiating Web SSO scenario based on [OIOSAML](https://svn.softwareborsen.dk/oiosaml.java/sp/trunk/webapp/). To test the system, I deployed it on the remote host. However `AssertionConsumerServiceURL`, where I specified URL, on which [Shibboleth](https://shibboleth.net/) idP (idP based on Shibboleth) should return the answer is not called.

`SAMLAssertionConsumer` - just a simple Java servlet. For a begin with, I just need to make sure that the response comes.

Generated AuthnRequest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer" 
    Destination="http://ip-of-identity-provider-here/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO" 
    ForceAuthn="false" 
    ID="_068712cd-......163720312" 
    IsPassive="false" 
    IssueInstant="2014-07-12T06:42:16.673Z" 
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0">

    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```

if I make request to my servlet `SAMLAssertionConsumer` direct:

```
http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer
```

Then it works.
I would like to know how to properly configure the the assertion consumer service. That is the part of the SP-metadata, where I specify the assertion consumer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:esia="urn:esia:shibboleth:2.0:mdext" entityID="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
                        MIID...XY7ZiQ==
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>
        <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
                        MIID...XY7ZiQ==
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </md:KeyDescriptor>

     <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"  Location="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer" ResponseLocation="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer"/>
     <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://ip-of-remote-system-here:8080/saml/consumer" index="0" isDefault="true"/>

    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
    <md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
       ...
    </md:AttributeAuthorityDescriptor>
    <md:Organization>
       ...
    </md:Organization>
    <md:ContactPerson contactType="technical">
      ...
    </md:ContactPerson>
    <md:Extensions>
      ...
    </md:Extensions>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was different. Was used incorrect keystore. Now everything is OK.

Initially, I assumed that `entityID` attribute must refer to a domain name, which specified in attributes `Location`. However, it is not. It just must be unique and it is better to use domain name for that.

[UnderstandingShibboleth, EntityNaming:](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/EntityNaming)

> Shibboleth identity and service providers are used in SAML
>   deployments, and as such,  they are assigned a unique name known as an
>   "entityID".

[Metadata for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML)V2.0, 2.3.2 Element :](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf)

> `entityID` [Required] -
>
> ```
>  Specifies the unique identifier of the SAML entity whose metadata is 
>  described by the element's contents.
> ```

[UnderstandingShibboleth, EntityNaming:](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/EntityNaming)

> Strongly recommended NOT to use the physical hostname of a server
>   running Shibboleth as the `entityID`. As time passes, things get moved
>   and that deployment may not always live on the same box.
>
> Additionally there may be multiple logical deployments of Shibboleth
>   on a single physical server, each requiring their own unique
>   `entityID`, so using the server's name doesn't scale beyond a single
>   one.

In the sandbox can be use physical addresses.